# Spring FeignClient - Treat RESTful xml response as JSON

Tags: java, spring, feign

I'm using Spring FeignClient to access a RESTful endpoint, the endpoint returns an xml, 
I want to get the response as a JSON, which in turn will map to a POJO.

```
1) When I access the endpoint on the browser, I get response as below, 
<ns3:Products xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.com/rest/core/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas/prod/v1">
<ProductDetails>
<ProdId>1234</ProdId>
<ProdName>Some Text</ProdName>
</ProductDetails>
</ns3:Products>


2) @FeignClient(value = "productApi", url = "http://prodservice/resources/prod/v1")
public interface ProductApi {

   @GetMapping(value="/products/{productId}", produces = "application/json")
   ProductDetails getProductDetails(@PathVariable("productId") String productId) 

    // where, /products/{productId} refers the RESTful endpoint 
    // by mentioning, produces = "application/json", I believe the response xml would be converted to JSON Java POJO. 


3) POJO
public class ProductDetails {
private String ProdId;
private String ProdName;

//...setters & getters 
} 

4) Service Layer 
ProductDetails details = productApi.getProductDetails(productId);
```

In the 'details' object, both ProdId &  ProdName are coming as null. 
Am I missing anything here? Firstly, Is it possible to get response as JSON instead of XML?

Comment: You may convert xml to json.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spring-rest-xml-response/

Answer (score 1):

If that RESTful service is programmed to return only xml-response, then you cannot ask it to give you json-based response.

But in your case the problem is with class where you want to map the result.
This xml response actually wraps `ProductDetails` tag into `ns3:Products`.

So you need to create another class which will hold a reference to `ProductDetails` object:

```
public class Product {   //class name can be anything 
    private ProductDetails ProductDetails;
    //getters, setters
}
```

Then change the type of `getProductDetails` method to `Product`.

If you still get nulls in your response, then it's probably because of ObjectMapper configuration. But you can always add `@JsonProperty` annotation for your fields (in 
this case it would be `@JsonProperty("ProductDetails")` for `ProductDetails` field in `Product`, and `@JsonProperty("ProdId")` and `@JsonProperty("ProdName")` for fields in `ProductDetails`).

Comment: What is `Category`? You haven't told us about this class. Maybe you could try to solve the problem further by doing similar steps?

Comment: Please see the update. For better understanding, I replace original names with my own, Added a wrapper class & included @JsonProperty annotation, now getting some error , 'feign.codec.DecodeException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.model.Product] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is '...HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of com.model.ProductDetails out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is '....MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of com.model.ProductDetails out of START_ARRAY ...'